# Proving a property of a Logic Formal Language

Tags: logic, formal-languages, context-free-grammar

I am stuck at this problem:

---

Let $\Sigma = \{\lnot,\lor,\land,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow,(,),P_1,...,P_n\}$  be an alphabet.

Now let's define the set of logical expressions $\mathscr{L} \subseteq \Sigma^\ast$ recursively as follows:

Rule #1: For each $i\in\{1,2,...,n\}$, $P_i\in \mathscr{L}$

Rule #2: For each $\phi \in \mathscr{L}$, $\lnot \phi \in \mathscr{L}$

Rule #3: For each $\phi,\psi \in \mathscr{L}$ and $@\in\{\lor,\land,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow\}$, $(\phi @ \psi)\in\mathscr{L}$

No strings other than those derived from Rules #1, #2 and #3 are in $\mathscr{L}$.

---

Prove that for all $\phi \in \mathscr{L}$ and $\psi\in\Sigma^\ast$, If $(\phi\land\psi)\in\mathscr{L}$ Then it must be the case that $\psi\in\mathscr{L}$.

---

I tried to prove it using structural induction, contradiction and several other ways but I wasn't  able to prove it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem you might have had with contradiction is that if you suppose $\psi\notin\mathcal{L}$, then by rule #3, it might still be the case that $(\phi\land\psi)\in\mathcal{L}$. The important thing to remember is `No strings other than those derived from Rules #1, #2 and #3 are in L`.

Comment: @Demosthene, Thanks for the reply. Of course by the recursive nature of the language $\mathscr{L}$, $\psi$ must be in $\mathscr{L}$ but I don't get how to prove it rigorously, I've tried structural induction but I got stuck.

Comment: @Demosthene, I showed that we can find $\phi,\psi\in\Sigma^\ast$ such that $(\phi\land\psi)\in\mathscr{L}$ but $\phi,\psi\notin\mathscr{L}$, Indeed we can take $\phi=P_1\land(P_1$ and $\psi=P_1)$ and so $(\phi\land\psi)=(P_1\land(P_1\land P_1))$ which is in $\mathscr{L}$.

Comment: Hint. The right way to prove this is given by the flag "context-free grammar".

Comment: @Saita - in your "example" with $\phi=P_1∧(P_1$ and $\psi=P_1)$ we are satisfying the rule 3 in a "vacuous" way. The "trick" is the "closure" condition: $P_1) \notin \mathscr L$ because we cannot "produce" it with the three rules : starting with $P_1$, there is no rules that allows us to "throw it" into $\mathscr L$.

Comment: To be more precise, $\mathscr{L}$ is generated by the grammar $S \to P_i + \neg S + (S \vee S) + (S \wedge S) + (S \to S) + (S \leftrightarrow S)\ $ and you need to prove that if there is a derivation $S \xrightarrow{*} (u \wedge v)$ where $u \in \mathscr{L}$, then $v \in \mathscr{L}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

We have to take into account the difference between the set $\mathscr L$ of *logical expressions* (the well-formed formulae) and the set $\Sigma^*$ of *strings*.

The string $P_1 \to P_2$ is a logical expression, while the string $\land P_1$ is not.

The "closure" condition following the three rules guarantees that only strings built-up from  the $P_i$ following the three rules is a logical expressions.

It can be equivalently expressed as :

> the set $\mathscr L$ is the smallest set $X$ of *strings* satisfying the rules 1,2,3.

---

Thus, the approach "by contradiction" is the right one; we will assume that :

> $\phi, (\phi \land \psi) \in \mathscr L$ and that $\psi \notin \mathscr L$.

Consider the set $X = \mathscr L − \{ (\phi \land \psi) \}$; we have that $P_i \in X$ and that if $\sigma \in X$, then $\lnot \sigma \in X$; thus, rules 1 and 2 are satisfied by $X$.

Consider now $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in X$; then $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in \mathscr L$ and thus, by rule 3 : $(\sigma_1 \land \sigma_2) \in \mathscr L$.

But the *string* $(\sigma_1 \land \sigma_2)$ is different from the *string* $(\phi \land \psi)$; it is enough to compare them and we have to conclude that the only way they can be equal (as *strings*) is when $\sigma_1 = \phi$ and $\sigma_2 = \psi$, and this is not possible, because $\sigma_2 \in \mathscr L$ and we have assumed that $\psi \notin \mathscr L$.

Thus, $(\sigma_1 \land \sigma_2) \in X$ and also rule 3 is satisfied by $X$.

But then $X$ satisfy rules 1,2,3 and this contradicts the "closure" condition, i.e. the fact that $\mathscr L$ is the smallest set of strings on the alphabet that satisfy the rules.

Comment: How do you prove formally that if $\sigma \in X$, then $\neg\sigma \in X$ ?

Comment: @Saita - you are welcome :) To be "perfect" it needs the proof of the "Lemma" regarding the equality of *strings* ...

Comment: @J.-E.Pin - because $X$ is $\mathscr L$ "minus" $(\phi \land \psi)$ and $\mathscr L$ satisfy rule 2. Again "by inspection", the "deleted" formula is not $\lnot \sigma$, for some $\sigma$, and thus we have no impact on the rule 2.

Comment: @Saita - see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA4) (2nd ed - 2001), page 4 : "If two sequences are equal $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle = \langle y_1,\ldots,y_n \rangle$, then it is easy to see that $x_i=y_i$ for $1≤i≤n$. (The proof uses induction on $n$)."

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really get why $(\sigma_1\land\sigma_2)=(\phi\land\psi)$ must imply that $\sigma_1=\phi$ (which will then imply that $\sigma_2=\psi$). There can be as many $\land$ characters as we want in the strings. The string $\phi$ may be for example a **proper** substring of $\sigma_1$ (or even a substring of $\sigma_1\land\{\text{some substring of $\sigma_2$}\}$). How do we overcome this difficulty and prove that it must be the case that $\phi=\sigma_1$.

Comment: @Saita - It is a "standard" result of elementary math.logic; see H.Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic (2nd ed - 2001)](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA40), page 40 : "**UNIQUE READABILITY THEOREM** The five formula-building operations, when restricted to the set of wffs, (a) Have ranges that are disjoint from each other and from the set of sentence symbols, and (b) Are one-to-one. In other words, the set of wffs is *freely generated* from the set of sentence symbols by the five operations." You can see the proof with the details for the case with $\land$ ...

Comment: But the Unique Readability Theorem only talks about elements from the set $\mathscr{L}$ and not on elements that are **not** from the set (like $\psi\notin\mathscr{L}$). And so how can we use this theorem when $\psi\notin\mathscr{L}$ and conclude from it?

Comment: More precisely, The Unique Readability Theoream says that for all $a,b,c,d\in\mathscr{L}$, If $(a\land b)=(c\land d$) then $a=c$ and $b=d$, but it doesn't says anything about elements that are not from $\mathscr{L}$. And so we cannot conclude from $(\sigma_1\land\sigma_2)=(\phi\land\psi)$ that $\sigma_1$ = $\phi$ and $\sigma_2=\psi$ (since $\psi\notin\mathscr{L}$).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've asked a new question, and if I will get an answer then this problem will be solved. Here's the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199716/proving-some-property-of-a-formal-logic-language

Comment: But you have to read carefully the proof : we are working with the assumption : $(\phi \land \psi) \in \mathscr L$ and we consider $σ_1,σ_2 \in X$; then $σ_1,σ_2 \in \mathscr L$ and thus, by rule 3 : $(σ_1∧σ_2) \in \mathscr L$. Now, both strings $(\phi \land \psi)$ and $(σ_1∧σ_2)$ are in $\mathscr L$ and the *unique readibilty* applies.

Comment: A detailed proof is in George Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=8jAwgCTgnycC&pg=PA10) (2008), pages 10-22.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The rules require you to put brackets around expressions formed with binary operators. Because brackets aren't used for any other purpose in the language the brackets have to balance. This means that if $\phi, \phi' \in {\cal L}$ and $(\phi \land \psi)$ is the same string of alphabet symbols as $(\phi' \land \psi')$ and is in $\cal L$, then $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are the same. To see this, show (by structural induction) that $\phi$ and $\phi'$ must both comprise zero or more $\lnot$ symbols followed either by $P_i$ for some $i$ or by a string of symbols beginning with a left bracket and ending with a matching right bracket (and in which brackets occur in balanced pairs). Since $\phi$ and $\phi'$ are the same, the two $\land$ symbols must be in the same position in the strings, hence you must have that $\psi$ and $\psi'$ are the same.

Comment: Do you mean to prove by structural induction that, for all $\phi,\phi'\in\mathscr{L}$ and $\psi,\psi'\in\Sigma^\ast$, If $(\phi\land\psi)=(\phi'\land\psi')\in\mathscr{L}$ then $\phi=\phi'$ and $\psi=\psi'$ ?

Comment: Yes: I have expanded the answer a bit.